# Activating Python Virtual Environment in Atom

Tags: python, package, atom-editor, conda, virtual-environment

Don't have much expertise in programming. Only picked up Python last summer.

I have installed both Atom and Conda on my computer. Recently, I've used Atom to edit my scripts in Python, then run the scripts via Command Line. As per standard practice, I created Virtual Environments where I installed packages I needed to run different Python scripts.

I now want to use Atom as an IDE, and so have installed the Script package on Atom so I can run my scripts in Atom itself. However, when I tried running a Python script that required the Python numpy package, I got this:

`ImportError: No module named 'numpy'`

This error is obviously going to appear for other packages that haven't already been installed in the root environment (I think?).

So now, my question is how do I activate the needed Virtual Environment in Atom? In other applications like Jupyter and Spyder, I would activate the Virtual Environment I needed then open the Application via Command Line, but I can't do that with Atom.

(If possible, is there a way to use Virtual Environments created by Conda)

Thanks

Comment: [script-runner](https://atom.io/packages/script-runner) supports virtualenv natively. Have you looked at that?

Comment: I just tried installing [script-runner](https://atom.io/packages/script-runner). Unfortunately, there was an error in installation [script-runner installation error](http://i.imgur.com/TumBfAy.png)

Comment: https://atom.io/packages/search?q=virtualenv

Answer (score 4):

One way is to start `atom` from the activated virtual environment. In this case, executing programs/scripts uses the configured python interpreter and imports the installed in the virtual environment.

**EDIT:**
It's been long though, it might be useful for people redirected to this question.

By installing `atom-python-virtualenv` you can create, change or deactivate virtual environments with atom editor.

Comment: This is great. However i have issues with setting up the conda environments path. 
They are in $HOME/opt/anaconda3/envs/ but that doesn't seem to work well. What do I need to point to?

Comment: If they're in `$HOME/opt/anaconda3/envs/` then you can point to virtual environment that you want like `$HOME/opt/anaconda3/envs/myPyVirtEnv` where myPyVirtEnv is your environment.

Answer (score 2):

The [hydrogen package](https://atom.io/packages/hydrogen) for Atom works well for this.

You will also need to install Jupyter into your conda environment and Hydrogen should pick up the IPython kernel automatically.